# Find and replace an option in select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find and replace an option in select box,
I am using this piece of code but this isn't working Help me out please!

```
$(".select" option).each(function() {
    if $(this).val() == "Unknown" {
        $(this).val().replaceWith( "---------" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this would also work:

```
$('#mySelect option:contains("Unknown")').text("---------");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tKP68/

Comment: $('select option:contains("Unknown")').text("---------");

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `option` inside the selector and use setter version of [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$(".select option").each(function() {
    if $(this).val() == "Unknown" {
        $(this).val("---------");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this...

```
$(".select option").each(function() {
    if $(this).val() == "Unknown" {
        $(this).val().replaceWith( "---------" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want achieve:

```
$('select option').each(function () {
    if (this.value === 'Unknown') { // You should always use === instead of ==
        this.value = '---------'; // Change value
        this.innerText = '---------'; // Change the option's text
    }
});
```